# Questions about NSUinteger and int

Tags: objective-c, int, jsonmodel, nsuinteger

I use JSONModel to capture data from json:

```
@interface BBTCampusBus : JSONModel

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * Name;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSUInteger Latitude;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSUInteger Longitude;
@property (nonatomic)         BOOL       Direction;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSUInteger Time;
@property (nonatomic)         BOOL       Stop;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * Station;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger  StationIndex;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSUInteger Percent;
@property (nonatomic)         BOOL       Fly;

@end
```

And I have the following code:

```
for (int i = 0;i < [self.campusBusArray count];i++)
{
    NSLog(@"index at nsuinteger - %@", (NSUInteger)self.campusBusArray[i][@"StationIndex"]);
    NSLog(@"index - %lu", index);
    if ([(NSUInteger)self.campusBusArray[i][[@"StationIndex"] ]== index)
    {
        numberOfBusesCurrentlyAtThisStation++;
    }
}
```

Actually `StationIndex` is a 1 or 2 digit integer. For example I have `self.campusBusArray[i][@"StationIndex"]` == 4, and I have `index` == 4, then the two NSLog all output 4, but it will not jump into the if block, or the `numberOfBusesCurrentlyAtThisStation++` won't be executed. Can somebody tell my why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets look at the line:

```
NSLog(@"index at nsuinteger - %@", (NSUInteger)self.campusBusArray[i][@"StationIndex"]);
```

`%@` says that an object will be included in the log, one that implements `description`.  That's good, because the end of the expression dereferences a dictionary, which may only contain objects.

`NSUInteger`, like `int` is a *scalar* type.  Like old-fashioned C, its just a group of bytes in memory whose value is the numerical value of those bytes.  An object, even one that represents a number, like `NSNumber` cannot be cast using the c-style cast (moreover, the precedence of the cast is low, this expression really just casts `self`, also nonsensical).

So it appears that `self.campusBusArray` is an array of dictionaries (probably the result of parsing JSON describing an array of objects).  And it appears you expect those dictionaries to have a key called `[@"StationIndex"]` with a numerical value.  That *must* be an `NSNumber` by the rules of objective-c collections (they hold objects).  Therefore:

```
NSDictionary *aCampusBusObject = self.campusBusArray[i];     // notice no cast
NSNumber *stationIndex = aCampusBusObject[@"StationIndex"];  // this is an object
NSUInteger stationIndexAsInteger = [stationIndex intValue];  // this is a simple, scalar integer

if (stationIndexAsInteger == 4) {  // this makes sense
}

if (stationIndex == 4) {  // this makes no sense
}
```

That last line tests to see of the *pointer to an object* (an address in memory) is equal to 4.  Doing scalar math on, or casts on, or comparisons on object pointers almost never makes sense.

Rewriting...

```
for (int i = 0;i < [self.campusBusArray count];i++)
{
    NSDictionary *aCampusBusObject = self.campusBusArray[i];
    NSNumber *stationIndex = aCampusBusObject[@"StationIndex"];
    NSUInteger stationIndexAsInteger = [stationIndex intValue];

    NSLog(@"index at nsuinteger - %lu", stationIndexAsInteger);
    NSLog(@"index - %lu", index);
    if (stationIndexAsInteger == index)
    {
        numberOfBusesCurrentlyAtThisStation++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! Now I found that I made this mistake because I forgot the value in a dictionary must be an object, so a NSUInteger will be boxed in to an NSNumber. Thank you again!